# RxJava - Emit when the third source change

Tags: observable, rx-java, rx-java2

Actually I have something like that

```
Observable.combineLatest(presenter.getSomething1(), fragmentVisibility, Pair::create)
  .compose(bindToLifecycle())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(this::trackPage, this::error));
```

where getSomething1() give some information needed to track my Fragment and actually it's work pretty well.

But I need to add another observable source, because I need more information from another observable. With combineLatest and 3 sources, trackPage() is called twice..

**Is there an operator like "emit only when the third observable change" ?** or something like that which would allow me to track from 3 sources and emit new tracking only when visibility change.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try what I suggested in my answer :) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure if I understood your scenario properly, but maybe you can chain the `combineLatest` with a new observable using `zipWith`. The the `zipWith` will only emit a value (applying whatever combination of the emitted values you want) whenever the `combineLatest` emits a value **and** the third observable emits a value too. [(RxJava zip documentation)](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

```
Observable.combineLatest(presenter.getSomething1(), fragmentVisibility, Pair::create)
  .zipWith(thirdObservable(), (pairEmissionFromCombineLatest, emissionFromThirdObservable) {
    // Combine the emissions and emit a new value (Here I am just re-emitting the emitted value of the combineLatest observable
     return pairEmissionFromCombineLatest;
   })
  .compose(bindToLifecycle())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(this::trackPage, this::error));
```